# Why scrolling down in chrome is not working after increasing div height

Tags: javascript

I have found a lot of answers of this question here, but nothing worked in Chrome but they works in Firefox..

I am trying to increase the height of a div using js/jQuery. In Chrome it increase the height but I cannot scroll down.
Here is what I tried to do.

```js
function h() {
  document.getElementById('d').setAttribute("style", "height:1500px");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="h()" class="btn btn-info">Select All videos</button>

<div id="d">
  Foo
</div>
```

I also tried jQuery `$("#d").css("height","1500px");` but I'm not able to figure out why scrolling down is not working.

Comment: What you have shown above works fine - as you can see from the snippet I added demonstrating your code. Have you set `overflow: hidden` on a parent element? Also, check the console for errors

Comment: Your code out of context if correct and working. https://jsbin.com/ronotiqewi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: nope, there is nothing like this.

Comment: I see it working correctly in Chrome.

Comment: wow. Yes I can see it too. But why I cannot see it my browser? Any idea?

Comment: We can't really help without seeing an example of the problem, or at least an error message. Check the console.

Comment: but it works in Firefox...

Comment: well, no error messages, and it scroll when I try to inspect the source and see console, it works also works when I try to resize the window.

Comment: We're talking about the code snippet above. That definitly works in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.It was some other javascript code which was causing this problem, I removed them and tried and it worked, so the code is perfect.

Thanks for helping..